# Android Studio freezes after updating to 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just updated my Android Studio from 1.4 to 2.0, on startup it freezes on splash-screen. is it possible to fix it or i have to download it again?

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: In my case I have updated Ram to 8 Gb it works fine for my Linux sysytem 14.04 64bit.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya see my answer, it works now

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan i am using windows 8 but now it works fine, thank you :)

Comment: @SuhasBachewar me too i have 8GB but now it works, thank you :)

Comment: I checked your answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer for my question, after trying many methods now it works fine.
This is how i resolved my problem by:

- Updating **Android SDK Tools** and the latest **SDK Platform**
- Removing the Android Studio cache folder situated in 
  `C:\Users\<username>\.AndroidStudioPreview2.0`
- Running android studio again

Comment: It's worth to mention that this is NOT the stable version of Android Studio, it's just a preview.

Answer (score 1):

Its very strange. I have also updated to 2.0 in my MAC, Ubuntu and Windows 10. I didn't feel any issues till now in any of these.

Please note that 2.0 is still a preview. You may have to wait till Google releases the stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you using?

For Windows, check the log of

```
C:\Users\<Username>\.AndroidStudioPreview2.0\system\log\idea.log
```

and paste here the last relevant entries on the bottom with a recent timestamp, containing an error message or indication of a possible freeze.

Also, check that you don't have any Android Studio, IntelliJ, or java-processes running before you start Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

At First **`Update Your Android SDK Tools (Support Repository )`**

> Actually Android Studio creates a local directory . AndroidStudio to
>   cache its own data. In most environments, this is acceptable. However,
>   the size of the directory can easily exceed 300Mb and, if you have a
>   space constraint on your home drive (or a roaming profile in windows),
>   this may be better off in some other place.

The location of this directory is placed in an idea.properties file in the **`bin/ directory`** of your AS is installed.