# After updating to canary preview 5, android studio does not work

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating to canary preview 5, android studio does not work.

It just show this image and nothing happens

[image]

i searched for any solution but to no avail

what is the wrong with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a *preview*, i.e. not ready for production use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem with my **Android Studio version 2 Preview 4** i asked a question here in SO after that i find the solution just look on my answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34027361/3077569)

This is what  i did

This is an answer for my question, after trying many methods now it works fine.
This is how i resolved my problem by:

- Updating **Android SDK Tools** and the latest **SDK Platform**
- Removing the Android Studio cache folder situated in
  `C:\Users\<username>\.AndroidStudioPreview2.0`
- Running android studio again

give it a try and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Android Studio. It is not good idea to use Canary Builds because it can be unstable.

I have obsession to have all apps upgraded to the newest version, and I used to use Android Studio Canary builds for a long time, and than some Canary Build caused some problems, and I have to reinstall. From than, I use only stable version of Android Studio.

Comment: Yes i understand it.. But There are new features which I want to use.. So I want to understand what is going on?! Thank you

Comment: Well, this features probably causes this. It will be soon in stable build.
You can reinstall studio and try again using Canary, or same more stable builds for example Beta..

Comment: OK I will give it a try.. Thanks